# WordPress show gallery image in original aspect ratio on click (Gutenberg)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new to WordPress and wanted to create a gallery on a page. I use the Twenty-Twenty-Four theme.

I created a gallery block and added my images. I would like them to be shown full screen on click in the original image ratio.

1. I only see the option to make images expandable when I select one image from the gallery. Is it possible to make all images in a gallery expandable (from one setting) or do I have to do it manually for each image?
2. The gallery automatically chooses an optimal image aspect ratio so that the gallery looks good. This means that some images are cropped. When expanding the image, I want it to be displayed in the original aspect ratio and not in the cropped version used in the gallery. how can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying php or Javascript to accomplish this? It would help if you mention how you want to go about and program this…

Comment: @Klaassiek sorry, I'm really new to WP and am not that sure how things work yet. I guess PHP and/or CSS snippets would be my go to.

Comment: Do you have a child theme already? If not, create one. What kind of gallery are you using?